# How can I access to the 'configuraition.yml' file?

Tags: redmine

I want to send e-mail from Redmine.
But I can't find configuration.yml.
So I hope to know the way to access the file.

I had searched the directory where it is default.
But I did't have permission.
So What I should do next?

I have only evaluate license.That is NG?

Please tell me the way to access to the file.

regards

Comment: Looks like you are using hosted redmine. Provide more details on where it is. Btw such questions usually are solved with service support.